# Intel gather instruction

Tags: intrinsics, avx2

I am a little confused about how Intel gather intrinsic works.

I have the following simple code. One of them is to set y[0]=y[1] = x[0], ... y[20002]=y[20003]=x[10002], the other one is to set y[i] = x[i], y[i+1] = x[i+2].

I just randomly print out some values to check the correctness. I found that I could get both y[10] and y[11] equal 2.46 if "zeros" is used. However, I will get a random number for y[11] when I use "stride", while y[10] is still 2.46. Any idea about what's wrong?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

void dummy(double *x, double *y) {
    printf("%lf, %lf\n", y[10], y[11]);
    return;
}

int main() {

    double x[20004];
    double y[20004];
    __m128i zeros = _mm_set_epi64x(0, 0);
    __m128i stride = _mm_set_epi64x(2, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20004; ++i) {
       x[i] = i * 0.246;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= 10000; j+=2) {
    #ifdef ZERO

        __m128d gather = _mm_i64gather_pd(&x[j], zeros, 1);
    #else

        __m128d gather = _mm_i64gather_pd(&x[j], stride, 1);
    #endif

       _mm_store_pd(&y[j], gather);
   }

    dummy(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Try a scale of 8 or `__m128i stride = _mm_set_epi64x(16, 0)`.

Comment: @Zboson Thanks a lot. It works now. But why it should be 16?

Comment: @Zboson Does it mean 2 bytes (16 bits)? Thanks.

Comment: because it uses bytes and a `2*sizeof(double)=16`.